# On a maximization exercise in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I am given a set $A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 , x+y \ge 0 \}$ and a function $f(x,y) = (x-y)^2 (x+y)$

I am tasked with finding $f(A)$.

So because $f$ is a continuous function and the set $A$ is arch connected and bounded $f(A)$ will be an interval, more precisely $f(A) = [\min_A f, \max_A f ]$.

So now I search for the critical points of $f(A)$, I start with the interior points and construct the system

$$\begin{cases} \nabla f = 0 \\ x^2 + y^2 < 1 \\  x+y > 0  \end{cases}$$

I find that $$(x-y)(3x + y) = 0 \ , \ (x-y)(-x -3y) = 0$$

So the only critical points for the interior are $x = y$ correct? I am lucky because if I substitute I get that $f(x,y) = 0$, but in a case like this; where I don't have an explicit solution, substitution would not generally work to find the value of the function at that critical point, so how could I do in general? Or do the solution to the system all fall in the category that they will give a single value to $f$ like $x = y$ did above?